# ajax query in razor page app not finding path

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, http-status-code-404

I have a razor app making the below call from [www.example.com/pricemap](http://www.example.com/pricemap)

On our test IIS server, this works without an error.  On our production IIS server it returns a 404 not found error.

If I type in the url [www.example.com/pricemap/](http://www.example.com/pricemap/) (adding in the forward slash) into Chrome it works.  If I put that same forward slash in the ajax url and remove the trailing forward slash from the typed in url in chrome, it returns the 404 error.

The code deployed to production is what was on our QA server - so it is identical.  Is there an IIS server setting that could possibly be causing this? Why would I get a fail on one server and success on another?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "Home/returnGridValues",
    data: {
        Year: year,
        ForecastName: forecastname
    }
}).done(
    function (data) {
        OnSuccess(data);

    }
)
    .fail(
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error getting values table " + errorThrown + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    )
```

Comment: *"If I put that same forward slash in the ajax url and remove the trailing forward slash from the typed in url in chrome, it returns the 404 error."* - Because a leading forward slash makes it an absolute path.  Can you just use the full absolute path for the AJAX URL?: `"/pricemap/Home/returnGridValues"`  Or could that potentially change?

Comment: Do you have http->https redirection only on the live site?